# How to make PDF files display on Android with <iframe></iframe>

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, iframe

I have a project to display PDF files with iframes that appear on computer or Android just fine. After I tried to make my simple project, I had trouble displaying PDF files on Android. Can you help me so that my project can be completed.

My Code is

```html
<iframe src="file.pdf" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Display on android as below

[image]

And Whereas when I access it on a computer like below

[image]

I want this PDF file to also display properly on Android like I access it on computer

Answer (score 0):

Have you try something like this ? :

```html
<iframe src="path/file.pdf" width="100%" height="500px">
```

For the next time, try to add the code you used to better understand how you got there

Comment: Yes, I've tried it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you show your code ?